# Command-line mv exclusion list

Tags: command-line, rename, scp

Is there a way to `mv`,`cp`, or any file operation such that I could specify all the files I *don't* want affected?

For example, say I have a folder with the files `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`, and I want to move `file1` and `file2` somewhere. Rather than explicitly naming the files to move (`mv file1 file2 /path/to/destination`), I want to name the files *not* to move and have all the others in the folder get moved (`mv --some-switch file3 /path/to/destination`)

Comment: I believe that `mv file1 file2 /path/to/destination` will not do what you want it to do

Answer (score 19):

- You can use the advanced globbing patterns in some shells to match all the files in a directory except for those matching a particular pattern. For example, in ksh, bash or zsh, the command

  ```
  shopt -s extglob   ## needed in bash only
  setopt ksh_glob   ## needed in zsh only
  mv /source/!(*.bak) /destination
  ```

  will move all files in `/source` to `/destination` except for the files matching `*.bak`. In zsh, you can also write `/source/^*.bak` if you first run `setopt extended_glob`, and more generally (again requiring `setopt extended_glob`) `/source/*~*.bak` (or `/source/a*~*.bak` for all files whose name begins with `a` except for `.bak` files, etc).
- Zsh has a mass copy/move/link command that can be used, amongst others, to move all files except for those matching a pattern. For example, the following command moves all files except `*.bak` from `/source` to `target`, and adds `.bak` to their name in the process:

  ```
  autoload zmv
  zmv '/source/(*)~*.bak' '/target/$1.bak'
  ```
- There are several commands called `rename` floating around. On Debian and Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/rename` is a perl script that moves files to a new name generated by a perl expression. You can exclude files from renaming by not generating a new name if the file is to be excluded. For example, the following command (using this particular `rename` program) moves all files except `*.bak` from `/source` to `/target`:

  ```
  rename 's!/source!/target! unless m!\.bak$!' /source/*
  ```
- You can use the `find` command to select the files you want to move. For example, the following command moves all regular files except `*.bak` in `/source` or a subdirectory into `/target` (note that the directory structure is collapsed):

  ```
  find /source -type f \! -name '*.bak' -exec mv {} /target/ \;
  ```

  or (more efficient if there are many files to move)

  ```
  find /source -type f \! -name '*.bak' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' /target/ {} +
  ```
- `rsync` is a generalization of `cp` and `scp` with very powerful include/exclude rules. For example, the following command copies all files except `*.bak` in `/source` or a subdirectory into `/target`, respecting the directory structure:

  ```
  rsync -a --exclude '*.bak' /source/ /target/
  ```
- `pax` is (amongst other things) another `cp` on steroids. Its exclusion rules are not nearly as powerful as rsync's, but it has the additional ability to rename files as they are copied. If you rename a file to the empty string, it's excluded from the copy. For example, the following command copies all files except `*.bak` in `/source` or a subdirectory into `/target`, and renames the files to `.bak` in passing.

  ```
  cd /source && pax -rw -pp -s '/.*\.bak$//' -s '/$/.bak/' . /target/
  ```

  The example above has the unfortunate side effect of creating directories called `foo.bak`, which can be avoided by combining `find` with `pax`:

  ```
  { cd /source && find . -type f; } | \
  pax -rw -pp -s '/.*\.bak$//' -s '/$/.bak/' /target/
  ```

Comment: Awesome. One possible correction: I think that the `find` command needs to end in `\;`

Comment: @Steven: Thanks, I keep forgetting you can only use `+` immediately following `{}`.

Comment: nice list, thx for that. :-)

Comment: what an answer, big thumbs up :)